# ReadingExceptionOccurred not being thrown

Tags: csvhelper

One of my TypeConverters is throwing an error. Unfortunately the ReadingExceptionOccurred delegate is not being called.

What is the correct way to handle TypeConverter errors outside of the TypeConverter itself.

```
csvReader.Configuration.ReadingExceptionOccurred = this.MyReadingExceptionOccurred;
csvReader.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true;
csvReader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap(csvMetricMap);

csvReader.Read();                                // Read the header

var row = csvReader.GetRecord<MyRowClass>();
...

private void MyReadingExceptionOccurred(CsvHelperException csvHelperException)
{
    // Never reached
}
```

I am using v3.4.0 of CsvHelper.

Comment: What does your reading code look like? What version of CsvHelper are you using?

Comment: Updated question to include the code for the read and the version number.